# "The element is missing the tag name following the namespace" Warning

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have an asp.net webform that works excellent,but the visual studio detects a warning says that "The element is missing the tag name following the namespace".
It is about tag helper that i use wrong.I have added my code snippet below.
How can i fix that problem?
Thanks in advance.

**My Code Snippet :**

```
<body>
  <asp:  @using (Html.BeginForm("LoginControl", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" })) />
  <%  { %>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" >
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" >
                    <div class="account-wall" style="background-color:darkgrey">
                        <img class="profile-img" src="images/Logo.png"
                             alt=""/>
                        <form class="form-signin" runat="server">
                            <input type="text" runat="server"  class="form-control" id="UserName" placeholder="Kullanıcı Adı" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" />
                            <input type="password" runat="server"  class="form-control" id="Password" placeholder="Şifre" required="required" />
                            <asp:button runat="server" ID="btnGiris" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" Text="Giriş Yap" OnClick="Unnamed1_Click"/>

                            <label>
                              <!-- <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me">
                                Remember me -->
                            </label>
                          <span class="clearfix"></span>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  <% } %>
</body>
```

Comment: I think you are mixing up asp and razor I've never seen a using statement wrapped in an asp tag as it means you have those orphaned brackets.  Also asp tags are usually runat server.  Another problem is that you have nested forms - you cannot do that

Comment: Your error though is complaining that at the top you have an `<asp: ` but do not define what type of tag it is - eg `<asp:button`

Comment: Thanks,but Which  type of tag i can add?I use "asp:" only to use my code running at server.

Comment: Why not use a normal form tag?

Comment: @Pete How Can i use a normal form tag?Can you explain please?

Comment: I think you need to google how to build a form in asp, there are millions of examples out there and is quite easy and basic

Comment: Avoid mixing MVC concept with webforms. You should use a single form tag with `runat="server"` attribute for webforms in single page (`asp:Button` is a server control), don't nest form tag designed for webforms with MVC `BeginForm`.

Comment: Well,how can i do that?Can you give me an example?